# How do you retrieve MIN value of a Apache Kudu table column?

Tags: python, apache-kudu

I am using PySpark to connect to my Kudu database. I want to retrieve a min value in a column with a set of predicates. Can't seem to find an option in the API

```
client = kudu.connect(host="myhost", port=1234)
table = client.table("impala::mydb.mytable")
scanner = table.scanner()
scanner.add_predicates([table['col1'] == 'test'])
scanner.set_project_column_names(['amount'])
myList = scanner.open().read_all_tuples()
```

The above will retrieve a list but I am not sure how to specify that I want the MIN value for amount column.

Tried

```
scanner.set_project_column_names([MIN('amount')])
```

but that results in MIN is not defined error.

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like you are using Impala already. You can use MIN function in Impala SQL to get the minimum value. E.g.:

```
SELECT MIN(amount) FROM mydb.mytable
```